# Transforming one list to another with commands

Tags: c#, f#, functional-programming

I have two lists and the purpose is to transform `list1` into `list2` by using a series of delete, move and append commands.

As an example; given following lists

```
list1 = ['A','B','C']
list2 = ['B','A','D','C']
```

commands to issue are:

```
commands = [
  'append D', 
  'move D,C', #move D over C
  'move B,A' #move B over A 
]
```

I have written a program to do this in c# in a very imperative way. I issue a delete command for every item that is not in list2. I issue append command for every item that is not in list1. When it comes to figuring move commands, I take items as a pair from list2 sequentially and issue a move command if the ordering is not same in list1.

My problem is that I am interested in writing another solution a functional way in F# or a similar language. Since I have almost no experience with functional programming I cannot wrap my head around how to approach this problem.

How would you solve this problem in a functional way?

Edit: My solution

```cs
var oldList = new List<char>() { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' };
var newList = new List<char>() { 'C', 'E', 'B', 'D' };

var deletes = oldList.Except(newList).ToList();
var appends = newList.Except(oldList).ToList();

var commands = new List<string>();
commands.AddRange(deletes.Select(x => String.Format("DELETE {0}", x)));
commands.AddRange(appends.Select(x => String.Format("APPEND {0}", x)));

var tmpList = new List<char>(oldList);
tmpList.RemoveAll(deletes.Contains);
tmpList.AddRange(appends);

bool changed = true;
while (changed)
{
    changed = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < newList.Count-1; i++)
    {
        char current = newList[i];
        char next = newList[i+1];
        int currentIndex = tmpList.IndexOf(current);
        int nextIndex = tmpList.IndexOf(next);

        if (currentIndex <= nextIndex) // same ordering, so continue
            continue;

        commands.Add(String.Format("MOVE {0}, {1}", current, next)); // move current over next
        tmpList.RemoveAt(currentIndex);
        tmpList.Insert(nextIndex, current);
        changed = true;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", oldList.ToArray()));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", newList.ToArray()));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", tmpList.ToArray()));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", commands.ToArray()));
```

Comment: If you're looking for a functional algorithm for diffing the two lists, I think you need to specify the problem more clearly - i.e. what commands are available and what effect do they have (e.g. if move refers to things by character then how are duplicates handled) and give the imperative code for your existing algorithm.

Comment: In the first sentence I have actually said available commands are delete, move and append. There won't be any duplicates in any list. All commands are executed on the old list.

Comment: At least supply your existing imperative code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for a greater ease of use, you should use descriminated unions to represent commands so you can actually execute them easily. Also, having prepend instead of append will work better for actually doing since F# lists are linked lists.

```
type Operation<'a> =
  | Delete of 'a
  | Prepend of 'a
  | Swap of 'a * 'b
```

We'll soon need function to get the items present in one list but not the other Let's call it `-`:

```
let (-) list1 list2 =
  List.filter
    (fun x -> not (List.exists ((=) x) list2))
    list1
```

Great. This enables us to write a function that takes two lists and returns a list of deletions needed to remove all extra elements from the first to get the second, as well as a function to do the same but for prepend operations.

```
let deletionOps list1 list2 = (list1 - list2) |> List.map Delete
let prependOps list1 list2 = (list2 - list1) |> List.map Prepend
```

The obvious next step is to write a function that gives us all the necessary swaps to get from one list to another. First, we need a function that can actually swap items in a list. A simple one that fits out needs might look like this:

```
module List
  /// Replaces all instances of a with b, and vice versa
  let swap a b l =
    l |> List.map (fun x ->
      if e = a then b
      elif e = b then a
      elif e)
```

Now here's the fun part, writing the swapOps function that tells us the necessary swaps to get from one list to another:

```
let rec swapOps listIn listOut =
  match listIn, listOut with
  | _, [] -> []
  | [], _ -> []
  | a :: listIn, b :: listOut when a = b -> swapOps listIn listOut
  | a :: listIn, b :: listOut -> Swap(a, b) :: swapOps (List.swap a b listIn) listOut
```

Almost there! We'll need functions to actually carry out these operations. Here's one way to write them:

```
let applyOp list op =
  match op with
  | Delete x -> List.filter ((<>) x) list
  | Prepend x -> x :: list
  | Swap(a, b) -> List.swap a b list

let rec applyOps list ops =
  match ops with
  | [] -> list
  | op :: restOps -> applyOps (applyOp list op) restOps
```

Finally, to tie it all together, you can write some code to take two lists and return the operations that, when carried out, will transform one list into another (assuming there are no duplicate elements). Not that my code could definitely could be improved to reduce repetition:

```
let ops listIn listOut =
  let dOps = deleteOps listIn listOut
  let listIn = applyOps listIn dOps
  let pOps = prependOps listIn listOut
  let listIn = applyOps listIn pOps
  let sOps = swapOps listIn listOut
  dOps @ pOps @ sOps
```

You can verify this using the `applyOps` function from earlier.

Comment: Sorry that this is a bit lengthy :P

Comment: wow thanks for taking time to write this lengthy answer! It will take some time for me to process all of this information

Comment: `Operation` type should be `Swap of 'a * 'a`, right? and also what is `e` in swap function?

Answer (score 0):

You can express this using a "fold" that applies the updates to the input list one at a time, each time producing a new output list instead of changing the existing list in place.

For example in F# you might first define an algebraic data type for commands:

```
type Command =
    | Append of char // append this char to the list
    | Move of char * char // move the first char over the second char
```

then write a function to apply a command to a list:

```
let applyCommand list command =
    match command with
    | Append c -> list@[c] // note that appending at the end is quite inefficient
    | Move (c1, c2) -> ...
```

and then finally use a fold to apply all your commands to the list:

```
List.fold applyCommand list1 commands
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am asking how to create that command list, not how to apply them.